# Acknowledeging a spring message

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I have a spring integration application and I am using message driven channel adapter for consuming the messages. This is the definition of the adapter -

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="messageAdapter" destination="inQueue"
                                    connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                                    error-channel="errorChannel"
                                    concurrent-consumers="${consumer.concurrent-consumers}"
                                    acknowledge="transacted"
                                    transaction-manager="transactionManager"
                                    channel="channel"
                                    auto-startup="true"
                                    receive-timeout="50000"/>
```

So this message goes to my core channel and then goes through a series of service activators. In between if there is a error than this message is moved to errorChannel where I handle the errors and decide on what needs to be done with this message. For one scenario I want the message to not rollback to the queue, is it possible? I am using 'transacted' in my adapter definition so I am not sure how to drive this behaviour. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You don't describe what the `transactionManager` bean is. If it's a `JmsTransactionManager`, remove it and the container will just use local transactions.

Then, the transaction will only roll back if the flow on the `error-channel` throws an exception. If that error flow exits normally ("consuming" the error), the transaction will not roll back.

If it's some other transaction manager (e.g. JDBC) then remove it and start the JDBC transaction later in the flow (i.e. don't synchronize the JMS and JDBC transactions; again using a local JMS transaction).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gary. I am using JPATransaction manager, so I effectively want that if database transaction is not committed than rollback message to the queue. With above settings it is working fine and message is getting rolled back, but for certain scenario's I want the message to not rollback (business scenarios). So is there a way to stop certain message from getting rolled back? If I remove transaction manager than all messages will stop going getting rolled back, so I hope I have to keep it.

Comment: If you synchronize the two transactions, you can't roll back one but not the other; that's the whole point of synchronizing them. See the last paragraph in my answer; use a local transaction on the container and start the JPA transaction in your message flow (after the adapter, e.g. with a `@Transactional` gateway or with a transaction advice on the `channel`). Then, after an exception, when the error flow gets the error, whether or not the JMS commits or rolls back is only dependent on what the error flow does.